# Does laplace transform of $y(x)^2$ exists?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, transformation

Suppose laplacian of $y(x)$ is $Y(s)$. Then what will be the laplacian of $y(x)^2$. Does it even exists?

Comment: It absolutely can exist. However you may not have a closed form solution for it.

Comment: Can you help me out solving this ode : $4a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y^2+(b+2s)y-sx,$

Comment: This is a nonlinear ODE and in general no rules exist to find solutions. You need to try to guess a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "rule" for that, only in some special cases, for example $y(x)=x^n$ or $y(x)=c$ or $y(x)=e^{ax}$.

Comment: Thanks fro your response. Actually I need to solve an ode   $4a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y^2+(b+2s)y-sx,$ where a,b,s are constants.

Comment: @SubhankarSil I think that's not solvable with Laplace transform, because it's not linear.

Comment: Then can you please suggest any way?

Comment: @SubhankarSil I have no idea how to do it, sorry. I've tried it with wolfram alpha too, but it can't solve it either.